# I am getting exception Getting "This file seems to be a binary doc/ppt/xls" when loading a .doc file using Docx4J.load

Tags: docx4j

Getting `This file seems to be a binary doc/ppt/xls` when loading a .doc file using Docx4J.load.
I tried loading a .doc by using docx4j but got the above exception.

Code as follows:

```
FileInputStream is= new FIleInputStream("C:\\Testing\\HELLO.DOC");
WordProcessingMLPackage ml= WordProcessingMLPackage.load(is);
```

Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, docx4j is complaining about having a `.doc` format (binary based, old), and not a `.docx` (newer format, XML based) .

Doc4xj is not capable of opening `.doc` files, only XML`.docx` .

Use only .docx files with it. This file format exists since Office 2007, and is the default one. Do not use the older one.

**To convert old .doc to .docx**, either load them into a version of MS Office and use `Save as...` and choose .docx format, or use various `.doc to .docx converter` existing on the internet, for instance : https://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-docx